# How to encode 256 bit binary string as base64?

Tags: javascript

I have 256 character string each character is 1 or 0 and I need to convert it to base64 how to do this?

Comment: `btoa(string)` ;)

Comment: Will this work as expected though? Because each character in op's string represents a bit and with `btoa()` "each character in the string is treated as a byte of binary data" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var your256bitstring;

// Base 64 encoded
var b64 = btoa(your256bitstring);

// :)
```